# ReactJS: onClick function executes before clicking button

Tags: reactjs

The function `SendCred()` executes the page is loading, but I want this to be called when the user clicks the `<button>`. What should I do?

```
 import React,{useState} from "react";

    export default function Signup(props){

      const sendCred=()=>{
        console.log("test")
      };


      return (
        <div className="row container">
          <button onClick={sendCred()}> Activate Laser </button>
        </div>
      );

    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sendCred` function is being called directly, when the result of your functional component is being evaluated and returned:

```
{/* The sendCred() function is being evaluated during render, and the 
    result of sendCred is being passed to the onClick prop */
<button onClick={sendCred()}> Activate Laser </button>
```

To achieve the desired behavior, consider specifying the value passed to `onClick` as a callback function that wraps a call to `sendCred()` (ie an arrow function as shown below). By doing this, the arrow function will be passed to `onClick` and, when a user click invokes `onClick`, the supplied arrow function will be called which will in turn cause `sendCred()` to be called:

```
export default function Signup(props){

  const sendCred=()=>{
    console.log("test")
  };

  return (
    <div className="row container">
      {/* Wrap sendCred() with an arrow function, and pass the arrow
          function to onClick as the callback to be invoked for user 
          click events on button */}
      <button onClick={ () => sendCred() }> Activate Laser </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Alternatively, you could also just pass the `sendCred` function directly to `onClick` - the key here is to ensure that you do not include a parenthesis pair (as you currently have done), as doing so will cause `sendCred` to be invoked during render:

```
{ /* Omit the () after sendCred */ }  
<button onClick={ sendCred }> Activate Laser </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just shouldn't call that function, just pass it directly to `onClick` listener

```
 import React,{useState} from "react";

    export default function Signup(props){

      const sendCred=()=>{
        console.log("test")
      };


      return (
        <div className="row container">
          <button onClick={sendCred}> Activate Laser </button>
        </div>
      );

    };
```

It can also be memoized with `useCallback` hook functionality([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback))

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

   export default function Signup(props){

     const sendCred = useCallback(() => {
       console.log("test")
     });


     return (
       <div className="row container">
         <button onClick={sendCred}> Activate Laser </button>
       </div>
     );

   };
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I was trying to pass a prop / parameter to my onClick function. The first part of Dacre Denny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237782/3505333) on this question made that clear to me.

The reason I was doing this is probably a common cause of this issue / Stack result.

I needed to access a dom element within a different component that was not available via documentQuerySelector, so I was attempting to pass a ref from a useRef hook down into the component and then act on it via the onClick function. The function executed at load and not on onClick. The pattern I ended up using to deal with this was, as follows.

```
/** Parent Component has access to props or ref and onClick Function **/

import { useRef } from 'react';
const formRef = useRef(); // ref has dom elements need accessing

const onClickFunction=()=>{
var inputs = formRef.current.querySelectorAll('input')
 /* Act on ref or props here via onclick function */
 };
 return(
 <ComponentWithPropsForOnClick formRef={formRef} />
 <ComponentNeedingOnClick onClickFunction={onClickFunction}/>
 )

/** Child component calling function with props or ref**/

export const SSDIBelow = ({ onClickFunction}) =>{

  <button onClick={onClickFunction}>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the function sendCred by calling it inside the onClick using "sendCred()". That event listener receives a function so you should assign sendCred alone.

Like this:

```
 return (
   <div className="row container">
     <button onClick={sendCred}>Activate Laser</button>
   </div>
 );
```

For the function you should know that you will receive the event that may be useful for you.

```
 const sendCred = useCallback((event) => {
   console.log('This is the click event:', event);
   console.log("test");
 });
```

As the onClick receives a function you can use clousures to take advantage of having some value you want sent along with the event.

The code will look something like this:

```
   import React, {useState} from "react";

   export default function Signup(props) {

     const sendCred = useCallback((value) => (event) => {
       console.log("I have a value:", value);
       console.log("I have an event:", event);
     });

     return (
       <div className="row container">
         <button onClick={sendCred('Laser')}>Activate Laser</button>
         <button onClick={sendCred('Engine')}>Activate Engine</button>
       </div>
     );
   };
```

That works because you return a function with value available for it to use and when the button is clicked the second function is executed with the event as a parameter.

hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when html template render on browser then
`sendCred()` immediately execute the function. If you want to execute on click then you need to pass it
`onClick={sendCred()}`

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

    export default function Signup(props){

      const sendCred=()=>{
        console.log("test")
      };


      return (
        <div className="row container">
          <button onClick={sendCred}> Activate Laser </button>
        </div>
      );

    };
```

Hope so it will help you to solve problem. Here reference document to check example https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html