# onClick doesn't fire event React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to toggle element by clicking on button, however it doesn't do anything. Also note that code is simplified as I didn't want to copy whole app, I just included parts I thought are important. Here is code:

1. Navbar.js ..Here I try to invoke the function it comes from context.js file where I setup my contextAPI

   ```
   import { useGlobalContext } from "./context";    
   const { openSidebar, openSubmenu, closeSubmenu } = useGlobalContext();
       <button className="btn toggle-btn" onClick={openSidebar}>
   ```
2. context.js

   ```
   const AppContext = React.createContext();

   const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
   const openSidebar = () => {
        console.log("test")
        setIsSidebarOpen(true);
    };
   return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={(isSidebarOpen,  openSidebar, closeSidebar)}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
   }

   export const useGlobalContext = () => {
   return useContext(AppContext);
   };

   export { AppContext, AppProvider };
   ```
3. App.js

   ```
   document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target);
   });
   ```
4. index.js

   ```
   import App from "./App";
   import { AppProvider } from "./context";



   ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
       <AppProvider>
        <App />
       </AppProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById("root")
   );
   ```

The event listener from App.js displays correctly event and also event.target which is the button. However I don't get any log to console from context.js where it should log  "test", not error, not warning, nothing... `onClick` is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Ive resolved it, the problem was in parentheses in context.js

here is old code:

```
return (
 <AppContext.Provider value={(isSidebarOpen,  openSidebar, closeSidebar)}>
     {children}
 </AppContext.Provider>
```

);

here is new one:

```
return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ isSidebarOpen,  openSidebar, closeSidebar }}>
        {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
);
```

I needed to replace () with {}

Answer (score 1):

You will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237726/reactjs-onclick-function-executes-before-clicking-button)

onClick={( )=>{openSidebar( )}}

Comment: well it did run the function indeed, but now I get openSidebar is not a function error ...

Comment: Try this onClick={( )=>{openSidebar}}

Comment: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: I think there must be a problem somewhere in context API where I send my functions as props, I don't  know what else could be wrong